# Expand first menu item by default and color background

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have a side menu in which i am displaying the menu headers from a for loop. I would like:

1. first menu item expanded on page load
2. expanded item to be highlighted (same background as when i hover)
3. only allow one menu item to expanded at a time. when expanding a menu header - ensure the previous expanded header is collapsed.

I am using the "aria-expanded" attributed in my anchor tag as a condition for my functionality but i am not getting consistent results as expecting.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let currIndex = index">
    <header>
       <a data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" [attr.aria-controls]="item.id" [attr.data-target]="'#'+item.id" (click)="toggleHeader(item.id, $event, currIndex)">
         <span>{{item.name}}</span>
         <span *ngIf="item.isActive" [ngClass]="ariaExpanded ?'chevronDown':'chevronUp'"></span>
       </a>
    </header>

    <ul *ngIf="item.isActive" class="collapse" [id]="item.id" data-toggle="buttons">
       <li>....</li>
       <li>....</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is my Typescript component:

```
public ariaExpanded: boolean;
public currentIndex: number;

public toggleHeader(id: number, event: any, currIndex: number){
   let header = this.arrayOfItemsData.filter((item)=> item.id === id)[0];
   if(header){
      header.isCollapsed = !header.isCollapsed;
   }
   this.currentIndex = currIndex;
   this.ariaExpanded = event.currentTarget.attributes["aria-expanded"];
}
```

Here is a link for a demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uihbx6
Not sure why it isn't toggling list on click in this demo.

Comment: can you add your code in stackblitz.com

Comment: @Chellappan i added my code in stackblitz and updated my post with link. Thanks!

Comment: @Chellappan not sure if i follow....

Comment: can you share the code page

Comment: @Chellappan https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uihbx6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are looping if you click the button it is showing all the button as active. if you want to avoid that add new property inside your data exaple i have added click.
So you can toggle using this variable and you can show the active state easily by using this value..

Check the exaple now if you click it will https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multi-toggle

Comment: I am testing it out. But will this also handle ensuring that only one item could be expanded at a time?

Comment: I may need a little more clarification on "item.click===true". Where does ".click" come from or property of what?

Comment: if you want to target single element on a loop. i have added the click property inside the json

Comment: is it possible to handle this without having to add the property inside the json?

Comment: i think this is best approach to do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176131/discussion-between-chellappan-and-bluepearl).

Comment: I did apply the suggested changes but i am still able to expand multiple items when i should be collapsing the previous item before expanding the clicked item.

Comment: did you add this code  this.items[currIndex].click=!this.items[currIndex].click; inside     toggleHeader method?

Comment: yes i did.. Should i add a conditional class on the <ul> tag to show only the expanded and to collapse items that are not the current index.

Comment: did you these class on html page  [ngClass]=" item.click===true ? 'win-icon-ChevronDown': 'win-icon-ChevronUp'"

Comment: yes and they are working fine with toggling correctly but i could still expand more than one item at the same time.

Comment: It is the same code... but i am not sure why in the demo the toggle is not working but in my code it is.. and it is the same. other than the demo is in angular6 and my code is angular2

Comment: and do i know why are you using bootrap Collapsible instead ngBootstrap?